# boost asio with ECDSA certificate issue

Tags: linux, boost, ssl, openssl, boost-asio

I am implementing SSL server using boost::asio.

The context initialization is shown in below code

```
    boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method SSL_version =
            static_cast<boost::asio::ssl::context_base::method>(param_values[ID_PROTOCOL_VERSION].int32_value);

    // load certificate files
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context> context_ = boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ssl::context>(
            new boost::asio::ssl::context(SSL_version));     
    p_ctx = boost::static_pointer_cast<void>(context_);

    context_->set_options(boost::asio::ssl::context::default_workarounds);

    context_->use_certificate_chain_file(cert_chain_file);
    context_->use_certificate_file(cert_file, boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    context_->use_private_key_file(cert_file, boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);

    context_->set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer | boost::asio::ssl::verify_fail_if_no_peer_cert);
    context_->set_verify_callback(boost::bind(&verify_certificate_cb, _1, _2));

    if (param_values[ID_CIPHER_LIST].int32_value != 0)
    {
        std::string cipher_list = "";
        generate_cipher_list(param_values[ID_CIPHER_LIST].int32_value, cipher_list);
        MA5G_logger::log(PRIORITY_INFO, "Supported cipher list %s", cipher_list.c_str());
        SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list((reinterpret_cast<boost::asio::ssl::context*>(p_ctx.get()))->native_handle(),
                cipher_list.c_str());
    }
```

in the `cipher_list`, I am supporting below list

```
AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
```

With `ECDSA` certificates if I use `cipher_list` given above then client can not connect to the server and gives error `"No shared cipher"`. But if I do not give `cipher_list` then the client can successfully connect to the server. The same cipher list works fine with `RSA` certificates.

The same ECDSA certificates work fine if I use `openssl s_server` with `-cipher` option to provide supported `cipher_list`

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: What does `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` return when you try setting the cipher list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sorry buddy I found the answer after lot of research.

The problem is with the cipher list and not with the code / certificate.

The same certificate uses `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA` cipher with openssl client-server while used `ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA` cipher for boost asio SSL client-server.

Anyways thanks @rkyser for your help!

Comment: Why is it so? ECDHE and ECDH are different ciphers, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

I found this buried in the FAQ of the openssl-1.0.1 source code:

> - Why can't I make an SSL connection to a server using a DSA certificate?
>
> Typically you'll see a message saying there are **no shared ciphers** when
>   the same setup works fine with an RSA certificate. There are two
>   possible causes. The client may not support connections to DSA servers
>   most web browsers (including Netscape and MSIE) only support
>   connections to servers supporting RSA cipher suites. The other cause
>   is that a set of DH parameters has not been supplied to the server. DH
>   parameters can be created with the dhparam(1) command and loaded using
>   the SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh() for example: check the source to s_server in
>   apps/s_server.c for an example.

So based on this, make sure you are setting your DH parameters using `SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh()`.

Comment: DSA and ECDSA certificates are two different certificate types in OpenSSL. In fact, his code will probably work with both RSA and DSS (DSA). And he would use `SSL_CTX_set_tmp_ecdh`, not `SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh`. Anyway, `s_client` should not suffer like MSIE or Netscape.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say thanks for posting this info, both rkyser and @jww. The docs are so damn confusing, it had me confused and thinking I needed to use tmp_dh callback and not tmp_ecdh callback. Looking back it should have been obvious to me, since ecdh != dh. The funny thing is though, that all the countless google searches on my problem yielded nothing about tmp_ecdh, not even a hint. This comment was it, and it helped immensely. Thanks again,